# Watching the offset of an element in the dom, when a different element changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm trying to find a way to monitor/watch the offset/width/height on a DOM element to catch any changes. However, I need also to catch any changes to an element if another element either moved the watched element or resized it. E.g. a DOM element above the watched object grew, and took up more space, resulting in the watched elements offset getting moved.

[Example to demonstrate what I need to watch/monitor](http://bit.ly/Salg1k)

I have implemented it using a timer, but a callback/watcher would be a lot better.

I've found several ways to watch changes on a particular element, but that would involve monitoring the entire DOM for changes, which isn't ideal.

Solutions that show how to monitor/watch changes on a particular item wont help, as they rely on the attributes/CSS changing on that particular item.
Examples of what's not working:
[jQuery CSS Property Monitoring](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Sep/12/jQuery-CSS-Property-Monitoring-Plugin-updated)
[Another watch tool](http://darcyclarke.me/development/detect-attribute-changes-with-jquery/)

I think a MutationObserver might work, but I haven't gotten it to work.

If anyone has ideas, please enlighten me with them!

Update 14.Oct 2013: Please see my own answer for a solution.

Comment: What have you tried with the `MutationObserver` so far, as this should trigger when attributes are altered. It might not get you the whole way there but it could possibly help -- unless it doesn't trigger on style changes. I've not actually checked that myself.

Comment: Ok just checked, `MutationObservers` do fire for a style attribute change (at least in FireFox).. but it doesn't tell which property was altered. still useful tho. This wont help with reacting if other elements (or if the window) shift(s) dimensions however. For that you will definitely need an interval/timeout checker and a window resize event listener... unless someone out there knows of js methods that allow you to hook into the user agents rendering process?

Comment: Exactly the same problem I experienced. It was quite easy to catch in-line style changes that might affect the offset of another item, but if there is a class change in the dom that changes the offset of the item to be watched a `MutationObserver` will only tell that a class has been added. I think I will add a mutation observer to just catch any changes, then do a manual `if offset.top != old_offset.top`. At least it's better than using timers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to make my own library, but forgot to answer this question with the library.

Source on [github.com/leifcr/jquery-csswatch](https://github.com/leifcr/jquery-csswatch) and examples here: [leifcr.github.io/jquery-csswatch/examples/](http://leifcr.github.io/jquery-csswatch/examples/)

Comment: This is exceedingly useful, and exactly what I needed. Kudos!